# Refering to classes created by annotation processing in Java

Tags: java, annotations, annotation-processing

Is it possible to refer to a class created by an annotation processor?

So in the sourcecode something like this:

```
GeneratedClass obj = new GeneratedClass();
```

GeneratedClass is not in the sorucefiles, but it will be generated by an annotation processor.

Comment: You can try a dynamic loading(runtime) to instantiate by name. That time the annotation processor would have completed processing.

Comment: What happens if you try the obvious thing (just referring to it as normal)?

Comment: @immibis The compiler cries compilation-error before the annotation processor gets a chance to do it's job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that I have been wrong. Refering to generated classes directly is possible.